# Flutter: Hive method 'get' method called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am trying to use Hive in my app as an alternative to Shared Preferences in Flutter. However, I keep getting an error that says:

```
I/flutter ( 4004): The method 'get' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4004): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 4004): Tried calling: get("counter", defaultValue: 0)

E/flutter ( 4004): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] 
Unhandled Exception: HiveError: This should not happen. Please open an 
issue on GitHub.
```

I followed all the steps showed in the documentation on *pub.dev*, however, I am not using any `TypeAdapters` and I am just trying to a counter that is an `int`. This is my implementation:

```
var box = Hive.box('box');
int counter;
        
 void initHive() async {
 await openBox();
 getCounter();  //Updated code
 }

Future openBox() async {
var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
Hive.init(dir.path);
box = await Hive.openBox('box');
return;
}
    
void getCounter() { 
counter1 = box.get('counter1', defaultValue: 0);
// I am not storing any value initially, hence as it is null I want it 
//to return the value 0 but the 'get' method keeps getting called on 
//null.
}
        
void initState() {
initHive();
super.initState();
}
```

I am unsure about a few things in Hive:

- When I use the `put()` method, does it persist the value of my
  counters?
- I am initialising the box in one dart file and calling that as a
  global variable throughout my app is that causing an error?
- Also I have only added the hive dependency because I don't need the
  rest. Could that also be causing a problem?
- Should I open the box each time I perform a `get` & `put` operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**
You can init `Hive` `box` in `main`

```
Box box;

Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(dir.path);
  box = await Hive.openBox('box');

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**Edit** 
The problem is code execution sequence
For your updated code to work , you have to put `getCounter()` in `initHive()`

**Reason**: `Hive box` is not ready because I/O need time and when execute `getCounter()` `box` is still `null` 
If you encounter `The method 'get/put' was called on null.` that means your `box` is not ready yet 
You have to check `async await` and code execution sequence again
And you do not need to open the `box` each time

code snippet

```
void initHive() async {
    await openBox();
    getCounter();
  }
```

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You need to `await _openBox()` and to do this in `initState()` you can use a function `hiveOperation()` to do `async await` 
code snippet

```
 void hiveOperation() async{
    await _openBox();
    updateInt();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    hiveOperation();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Step 2: https://pub.dev/packages/hive#usage, You can use `Hive` just like a `map`. It is not necessary to `await Futures`. 
You do not need to `await newBox.put('updateInt', updateInt);` just `newBox.put('updateInt', updateInt);` will work

output

```
I/flutter ( 5675): 30
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Box box;

Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(dir.path);
  box = await Hive.openBox('box');

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  int counter1;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void getCounter() {
    counter1 = box.get('counter1', defaultValue: 0);
    _counter = box.get('counter1', defaultValue: 0);
    print(counter1);
    print(_counter);
// I am not storing any value initially, hence as it is null I want it
//to return the value 0 but the 'get' method keeps getting called on
//null.
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    //initHive();
    getCounter();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce in my example code. please post your full code, thanks.

Comment: Hi I have updated my problem to be more precise, I'd appreciate if you could help. Thanks!

Comment: I have update my answer. box is null because I/O need time.

Comment: You can init Hive box in main, please check my updated answer. that way you will not encounter error. I also update full code

Comment: Thank you! Calling openBox() in main() worked for me.

Comment: shouldnt it be possible to await till i/o is done? What's the point of doing await if it bypasses it because io is still working. in my case i run the openBox in initState and it finishes opening the Box after Widget build() where my code resides to access the hive box. resulting in the same error